# How to set AncestorKey to Entity when writing to Datastore from Apache Beam in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'd like to store two kinds of entities linked by a composition.

A **User** have multiple **Order** but I don't know how to set the relationship such as explained [in the doc for AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths).

```
    Key.Builder keyBuilder = DatastoreHelper.makeKey(kind, new String(order.getOrderId()));
    Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder();

    entityBuilder.setKey(keyBuilder);

    entityBuilder.putProperties("order_id", DatastoreHelper.makeValue(order.getOrderId()).build());
    entityBuilder.putProperties("user_id", DatastoreHelper.makeValue(order.getUserId()).build());

    return entityBuilder.build();
```

I'd like to use a function like **setAncestor()** or **addAncestor()** any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

The ancestor relationship is on the key of the entity not the entity itself.  So you can either pass the parent key to [`DatastoreHelper.makeKey`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/java/datastore/src/main/java/com/google/datastore/v1/client/DatastoreHelper.java) or use `addAncestors` on the key builder like you referenced [in the doc for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-key-with-parent-java)